# sum of Max numbers in Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

`arr` is an int array of 5 elements only.
We need to calculate sum of  only 4 smallest minimum  numbers and sum of 4 largest maximum mumbers from these 5 elements.

example:  `int[] arr= {5,2,3,4,1}`

In this array,
4 smallest minimum numbers are: `1,2,3,4` so  `totalMin = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10`

Largest 4 Maximum numbers  are: `5,4,3,2`  so `totalMax = 14`

So output will be : `10, 14`.

My below code is working correctly for **40%** cases, but not working for **60%** cases.

I sorted Array first .. so that always smallest numbers will be:  `arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]` and **MAX** will be `arr[4], arr[3], arr[2], arr[1]`

HackerRank showing that my this answer is wrong for some cases , but those are locked. I dont know those cases... I am also wondering what will be those cases?

Can anybody explain me? What wrong am doing here?

You can check more details of question here:  https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem

```
static void miniMaxSum(int[] arr) 
{
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    Integer min=arr[0]+arr[1]+arr[2]+arr[3];
    Integer Max=arr[4]+arr[3]+arr[2]+arr[1];
    System.out.println(min+" "+Max);
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpfull if you could provide one of those "60%" cases where your program doesn't work.

Comment: hackerRank showing those cases locked..i also dont know those cases , thats why am asking here...  what might be other cases?

Comment: Perhaps you missed the hint: "Beware of integer overflow! Use 64-bit Integer."

Comment: Also, though unrelated to your problem: Don't give variables names that begin with a capital letter (`Max` - use `max`). Also, don't use `Integer` when you can use `int` (or `Long` where you can use `long`). There is no point in creating objects, though for such a small program it doesn't matter.

Comment: It is possible that beyond the problem reported by Eran cause your decision of sorting the array you exceed the timeout  limit for the problem.

Comment: @Eran- Thanks for focusing me on integer overflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the given constraints, the largest sum you can produce is 4 * 10<sup>9</sup>, which overflows an integer. However, it fits nicely into a `long`, so summing the values as `long`s should do the trick:

```
long min = (long)arr[0] + (long)arr[1] + (long)arr[2] + (long)arr[3];
long max = (long)arr[4] + (long)arr[3] + (long)arr[2] + (long)arr[1];
```

Note, however, that this solution still has an O(nlog(n)) time complexity due to the sorting.
This can be improved to O(n) - in a single pass of the array you could get the sum, min and max of it, and then subtract the maximum from the sum to git the "min" value and the minimum from the sum to get the "max" value.

Using an `IntStream` will do most of the heavy lifting for you:

```
IntSummaryStatistics stat =  Arrays.stream(arr).summaryStatistics();
long min = stat.getSum() - stat.getMax();
long max = stat.getSum() - stat.getMin();
```

Comment: The `IntStream` class seems perfectly suited to this class of problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
long first =  arr[0];

long second =  arr[1];

long third =  arr[2];

long fourth =  arr[3];

long fifth =  arr[4];

long min = first + second + third + fourth;

long Max  = second + third + fourth + fifth;
```

Above will work, the reason being is input and result may exceed 32 bit so we have to use long and we have cast each value of long before doing the sum operation because, it may also exceed more than **32 bit**

Answer (score 0):

Yes. My mistake, was not converting **int** to **long** (64-bit Integer).Error was because of **integer Overflow**

```
    static void miniMaxSum(int[] arr) 
     {
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        long min= (long)arr[0]+(long)arr[1]+(long)arr[2]+(long)arr[3];
        long max= (long)arr[4]+(long)arr[3]+(long)arr[2]+(long)arr[1];
        System.out .println(min+" "+max);
     }
```

Comment: You don't need to use `Long`. It's better to use `long`, and more readable, too. `long min = (long)arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3]` - shorter, easier to understand.